# Spring data MongoDB querying document with a field of type BigDecimal

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

The project I am working on has a MongoDB document with a `BigDecimal` field. This is causing issues with the query:

```
@Query(" 'amount' : {'$gt': '0'} ")
```

returns 0 results and I am not sure if it is because `BigDecimal` gets converted to type `String` on MongoDB. Is there any way to get around this without changing the field type or providing a custom converter?

Comment: i think '0' is the problem, try 0 without ''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a customconverter to avoid this problem. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-index-annotations-converter#converters

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference

Comment: Looks be the only resolution.